# I somehow renamed my Music folder to Pictures, How to chamge back to Music

Tags: ssd, windows-10

I'm running Windows 10 64bit with an SSD as the boot device.  I was trying to link a music folder on an HDD that is my files drive since the SSD is only 250 Gbyte.  I got confused and somehow renamed the music file to a second Pictures file.  I can't change the name of the folder back to Music.  Is there a way to do this?